# Android: How to stop uploading a file to google drive

Tags: android-activity, google-drive-android-api

I know how to upload a file to google drive, using an asynchronous task, able to cancel the async task. But, how to stop the uploading process.

```
insert = service.files().insert(image, image_content);
insert.execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

please refer to below link, By Closing FileinputStream you can stop uploading process.

[Android How to stop/kill/cancel Media Upload or Download](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21073758/android-how-to-stop-kill-cancel-media-upload-or-download)

```
 java.io.File fileContent = new java.io.File(imageUrl);

     fileStream = new FileInputStream(fileContent);

     InputStreamContent mediaContent = new InputStreamContent("image/jpeg", new BufferedInputStream(fileStream));   

    insert = service.files().insert(image, mediaContent);

    insert.execute();
```